# Razer Kraken Pro microphone not being recognized

Tags: 16.04, drivers, sound, microphone, headset

When i plug in my headset, it does not recognize the microphone. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 Long Term Support. I have tried a lot of tutorials but it just does not seem to work, so here i am trying to get some help.\
EDIT: It is a 3.5mm jack headset.

Comment: Is it the 3.5mm jack or USB model? The former should work like any other analogue headset.

Comment: install `pavucontrol` and have a look at the settings it show. also have a look at `alsamixer` from command line and see if anything is muted.

Answer (score 1):

0 - Connect all cables properly and adjust the microphone (some models come with retractable mic, so pull it out a bit or move accordingly)

1 - Left click sound/volume control icon and set some volume for both speakers and microphone

2 - Still in the same menu of step 1, click Sound settings...

3 - In tab Output, frame Play Sound Trough, select the alternative corresponding to your device. Probably you will have, at least, one option, the built in speakers. It's likely to have also an "Analog Output" corresponding to your device whose subtitle will be familiar to you and resembles your device model (ex: mine is "Razer Kraken Tournament Edition")

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following things in order to see if your microphone might be muted:

- check that the microphone is connected into the right jack;
- go to System Setting>Sound>Input and check if the microphone is muted;
- run `alsamixer` and check if the microphone is muted by selecting your sound card (press F6) and then by going to recording devices (press F). You can move through the different items by using your arrow keys, increase/decrease volume with arrow keys, mute/unmute using M or space;
- run `pavucontrol` (`sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`), go to the Configuration Tab and check set the Profile to Analog Stereo Duplex, then go to the Input Devices tab and check if the microphone is muted. Unmute it and split the channel in 2 channels (Front Left - Front Right) by pressing the icon in the upper right corner. Try to turn each channel at a time to 0 and the other to maximum and check if the microphone starts working;

You may also have some problems with your Sound Card. It would be really nice to have some info from you, like:

- run `lspci` and paste the output here
- run the following command and paste the output somewhere and link us to it.

  `cat /proc/asound/{version,cards,devices,hwdep,pcm,seq/clients}; ls -l /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/; sudo rm /etc/asound.conf; sudo rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.asound* ;sudo rm ~/.pulse-cookie; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install aptitude; sudo aptitude install paman gnome-alsamixer libasound2-plugins padevchooser libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio; sudo lshw -short;ls -lart /dev/snd; find /lib/modules/`uname -r `| grep snd ;cat /dev/sndstat; lspci -nn; lsusb; sudo which alsactl; sudo fuser -v /dev/dsp /dev/snd/* ; dpkg -S bin/slmodemd; dmesg | egrep 'EMU|probe|emu|ALSA|alsa|ac97|udi|snd|ound|irmware'; sudo /etc/init.d/sl-modem-daemon status; sudo grep model /etc/modprobe.d/* ; sudo dmidecode|egrep 'anufact|roduct|erial|elease'; lsmod | egrep 'snd|usb|midi|udio'; pacmd list-sinks; aplay -l; sudo alsa force-reload;  ubuntu-support-status ; sudo lshw -C sound`

You can always look for more help with Sound Troubleshooting [HERE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure).

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6k2MvtQy and by the way i am on a laptop, it uses my internal microphone. But i dont know if it just doesnt recognize the headset microphone or that is just doesnt let me overwrite the laptop mic

Comment: wait sorry that one is for the first command here is the long command https://pastebin.com/4Fa40WND

Answer (score 0):

I think i found what is causing the problem, when i am on windows it gives me a menu to select what audio device i am using. I just need to know how you can do that on linux. On windows there was an option in the realtek hd audio manager but on linux i can not really seem to find the audio manager on linux.